# ZSH How to bind unicode character?

Tags: zsh, zshrc, zsh-completion

My keyboard layout is very similar to classic latin but with some extra characters like ç, ş, ö, ü, ğ, İ.

I wanted to bind these chars in zsh like “bindkey “^Ş” autosuggest-accept” how can I do that?

Comment: From [here](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Guide/zshguide04.html): _By the way, note that zsh only handles ordinary 8-bit characters at the moment. It doesn't matter if some do-gooder on your system has set things up to use UTF-8 (a UNIX-friendly version of the international standard for multi-byte characters, Unicode) to appeal to the international market, I'm afraid zsh is stuck with ISO 8859 and similar character sets for now._